# Bootrstrap masonry grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[click here for sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wouhM.png)

[click sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi6Cy.png)
how i can create masonry type cards by using bootsrap col,
what classs do i need to use, or do i  need to re code the structure?

```css
.box1{
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  
}
.box2{
  height:220px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: row>col-md-3>div.card the layout go like this